# Average signal over several intervals with granges in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

I have a genome-wide ChIP-seq signal imported from a bedGraph file into a GRanges object. I'd like to plot the average signal over fixed-width intervals covering all the peaks. How can I extract the signal into numeric vectors so that I can average them?

By way of example consider:

```
library(GenomicRanges)
set.seed(1)

signal <- GRanges(
    seqnames = Rle(c("chr1"), c(10)),
    ranges = IRanges(1:10*10, end = 1:10*10+5),
    score = runif(10))

intervals <- GRanges(
    seqnames = Rle(c("chr1"), c(5)),
    ranges = IRanges(1:5*20 + floor(runif(5)*4), width = 10))
```

so the signal looks like:

```
GRanges with 10 ranges and 1 metadata column:
       seqnames     ranges strand |              score
          <Rle>  <IRanges>  <Rle> |          <numeric>
   [1]     chr1 [ 10,  15]      * |    0.2655086631421
   [2]     chr1 [ 20,  25]      * |   0.37212389963679
   [3]     chr1 [ 30,  35]      * |  0.572853363351896
   [4]     chr1 [ 40,  45]      * |  0.908207789994776
   [5]     chr1 [ 50,  55]      * |  0.201681931037456
   [6]     chr1 [ 60,  65]      * |  0.898389684967697
   [7]     chr1 [ 70,  75]      * |  0.944675268605351
   [8]     chr1 [ 80,  85]      * |  0.660797792486846
   [9]     chr1 [ 90,  95]      * |   0.62911404389888
  [10]     chr1 [100, 105]      * | 0.0617862704675645
  ---
  seqlengths:
   chr1
     NA
```

and the intervals look like:

```
GRanges with 5 ranges and 0 metadata columns:
      seqnames     ranges strand
         <Rle>  <IRanges>  <Rle>
  [1]     chr1 [ 20,  29]      *
  [2]     chr1 [ 40,  49]      *
  [3]     chr1 [ 62,  71]      *
  [4]     chr1 [ 81,  90]      *
  [5]     chr1 [103, 112]      *
  ---
  seqlengths:
   chr1
     NA
```

so I'd like to average the vectors:

```
Rle(c(0.372, 0), c(6, 4))            # [ 20, 29]
Rle(c(0.908, 0), c(6, 4))            # [ 40, 49]
Rle(c(0.898, 0, 0.945), c(4, 4, 2))  # [ 62, 71]
Rle(c(0.661, 0, 0.629), c(5, 4, 1))  # [ 81, 90]
Rle(c(0.061, 0), c(3, 7))            # [103,112]
```

How can I do this without for loops and lots of tedious error-prone interval arithmetic? I was hoping the GenomicRanges package would contain this sort of functionality but I couldn't see it in the manual. I've been trying to use subsetByOverlaps but this doesn't seem to carry over the signal score into the results, nor does it seem to help to extract the Rle vectors above.

Answer (score 2):

I think I might have figured it out. I can apply the `getScores()` function below to each range in intervals. The functions uses `findOverlaps` as adapted from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9913411/959926:

```
getScores <- function(interval) {
    scores <- Rle(0, width(interval))
    bases <- GRanges(
        seqnames = seqnames(interval),
        ranges = IRanges(start(interval):end(interval), width = 1))
    overlaps <- findOverlaps(signal, bases)
    scores[start(bases)[subjectHits(overlaps)] - start(interval) + 1] <- score(signal)[queryHits(overlaps)]
    scores
}
Reduce('+', sapply(split(intervals, 1:length(intervals)), getScores)) / length(intervals)
```

It seems to work so far but any improvements would be welcome. For instance it is quite slow when signal and/or intervals are long.

Answer (score 1):

What about this solution?

```
overlaps <- findOverlaps(signal, intervals)
signal <- signal[overlaps@queryHits]
averagedSignal <- aggregate(score(sites), list(overlaps@subjectHits), mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 overlaps <- findOverlaps(signal, intervals)
 sites <- signal[queryHits(overlaps)]
 intervals$averagedSignal <- aggregate(score(sites), list(subjectHits(overlaps)), mean)
```